# Is a field endomorphism an isomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $F$ be a field and $\sigma:F\to F$ is a field embedding. I think that $\sigma$ should be field isomorphism, but i don't know how to prove it.

If it is not true, can you suggest me some counter example?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take $F = \mathbb{F}_{p}(t)$ and $\sigma : x \mapsto x^{p}$. This is Frobenius's morphism and is not an isomorphism.

For an example in characteristic zero, consider $F = \mathbb{R}(x)$. Because of the universal properties for the rings of polynomials and for the fields of factions you have a unique field morphism $ \mathbb{R}(x) \to \mathbb{R}(x)$ sending $x$ to $x^2$ that extends the inclusion $ \mathbb{R} \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}(x)$. Observe that $x$ is not in its range.

Comment: Thank you. But could you find some counter example in characteristic zero? Because I am doing it in char 0.

Comment: @Andrew Added a counterexample in characteristic zero.

Comment: Thank you! I just have read your reply now. It's very interesting!